# Можно ли использовать Tor вместо Proxy на php?

Tags: php, proxy, tor

Задача банальна, есть "зеркало" иностранного сайта, которое в реальном времени берет с него данные, переводит их на русский и выводит пользователю.

Иностранный сайт особо не банит запросы, но иногда все же часть запросов к одному из разделов сайта банится.

Обойти это дело можно через proxy, но, понятное дело, что это не бесплатно.

Можно ли отправлять запросы на этот сайт из своего php скрипта как через tor браузер? Цель одна - избежать блокировок по ip. Я не очень знаком с технологией tor, потому вопрос может быть корявым.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С точки зрения скрипта Tor это тот же прокси, соединение с ним ничем не отличается от любого другого соединения через прокси-сервер.

Просто устанавливаете и настраиваете Tor, после чего в качестве SOCKS5-прокси указываете тому, кто делает запросы, адрес `127.0.0.1:9050` (если ничего не меняли в настройках дополнительно). В случае `curl` это будет выглядеть так:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_SOCKS5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, '127.0.0.1:9050');
```

или так:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, 'socks5://127.0.0.1:9050');
```

Comment: Получается бесплатная альтернатива сервисам proxy серверов? Или не все так радужно?

Comment: Как я понимаю, трафик пойдет через tor, но ip будет статическим. Ну или по крайней мере он не будет меняться часто.

Answer (score 1):

Все не так радужно, потому что Тор очень сильно лагает.
Если у сайта к которому идут обращение есть IPv6, то прокси будут очень дешевые.
Еще есть вариант прикинутся гугл-ботом - вдруг его не банят.